# Speed up Excel Macro as Opening

Tags: vba, excel

So the whole scope of this Excel file **is to copy and paste from other 27 external files to the current Excel file one by one.** to show what I mean, following are the code examples and a stimulated capture picture.[image]

### Macros(line # including space line):

**1. Importing Sub**

In my file, I have 27 subs like this. It's longer than this example. My real macro has 179 lines as the total. In this example, it only has 51 lines.

The only thing will be changed is the row numbers as the word row in VBA code in line 6.

```
    Sub Import_NJ()

    Dim Row As Integer, PathFileOpen As String, NameFileOpen As String, 
    TypeFileOpen As String, FullFileName As String, TabCopy As String, ModelFileName As String

    Let Row = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells("2", "D").Value
    Let PathFileOpen = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells(Row, "A").Text
    Let NameFileOpen = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells(Row, "B").Text
    Let TypeFileOpen = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells(Row, "C").Text
    Let FullFileName = PathFileOpen & "\" & NameFileOpen & TypeFileOpen
    Let TabCopy = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells(Row, "J").Text
    Let ModelFileName = Worksheets("Control_Table").Cells("10", "B").Text

        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=FullFileName, UpdateLinks:=0

    'Copy Income Statement
        Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("9", "C").Resize(5, 120).Copy         'Revenues
        Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("4", "AW").Resize(5, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("18", "C").Resize(4, 120).Copy        'Prod Costs
        Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("11", "AW").Resize(4, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("25", "C").Resize(26, 120).Copy       'Employee Related thru maintenance
        Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("17", "AW").Resize(26, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("53", "C").Resize(3, 120).Copy       'D&A
        Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("46", "AW").Resize(3, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues



        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

2. Batch Import Sub

although it only shows 7 callings, I have 27 calling in my file

```
    Sub batch_import()
    With Application

        Call Import_NJ   
        Call Import_MD 
        Call Import_PA   
        Call Import_OKC 
        Call Import_CA    
        Call Import_HI 
        Call Import_IN    

    End With

        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        MsgBox _
        ("Batch loading Completed.")

    End Sub
```

What I tried:

1. Turn off the automatic calculation in each Sub, as you see in the first example Macro. and also others application as many as I could.
2. I didn't shut down the screen updating since my manager wants to see it.
3. I activate the automatic calculating at the end of the Patch sub.

I guess the reseason slowing down the whole process is that I have more than 27 subs in the module.Also, there are a bunch of formulas filled in the worksheets.

Are there any ways to speed up the Macro regarding opening the file and running it? Let me know if I need to elabrate more on this question. Thanks for in advance and read through my question. : )

Comment: Does `.Cells("9", "C")` instead of `.Cells(9, "C")` actually work? I did not know that.

Comment: your issue is that your interacting with the spreadsheet itself too much which is why its taking a while to run. As a rule of thumb you should avoid copy and pasting, selecting, activating.... Anything that directly "touches" the object/application should be avoided at all costs

Comment: @Jeeped - It does! I didn't know either but just checked and it works. Neat "trick"!

Comment: @Jeeped. That did work! ha

Comment: If actually opening the external files is taking a good portion of the time, save them as XLSB and the file load time should be halved (at least).

Comment: So, the code above works, yes? It's just slow/could be improved? This may be better over at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Also, as mentioned by @DougCoats - don't `.copy`/`.paste`, especially if you just need values. You can do this: `Range([destination Range]).Value = Range([copy range]).Value` which should be faster.

Comment: @DougCoats So that sounds like there is no ways around it

Comment: @BruceWayne yes, the code worked. it just ate up my time to open it and save it and calculate it. and thanks for the new direction! I will post it to there.

Comment: Not exactly. Instead of Range.copy you could say workbork1.range= workbook2.range. Or you could store things in arrays :D

Comment: @DougCoats could you point me a direction to do it in arrays?

Comment: Sure, I can find plenty. Or if you give me a1 few ill start a chat for us and give you some basic instruction

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx this is a good start. the more i think about it arrays are useful but IDK how much of a boost youll get. If youre moving tons of stuff per workbook you open, then yes maybe theyll be useful. The issue will be how you handle it.

Comment: @DougCoats  "a1 few ill" what does that mean? And sure chatting with you, how are we gonna do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only pasting values; transfer values directly instead and remove the clipboard from consideration. Either the source or the target could be referenced within a With ... End With.

This,

```
    Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("9", "C").Resize(5, 120).Copy         'Revenues
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("4", "AW").Resize(5, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("18", "C").Resize(4, 120).Copy        'Prod Costs
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("11", "AW").Resize(4, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("25", "C").Resize(26, 120).Copy       'Employee Related thru maintenance
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("17", "AW").Resize(26, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports").Cells("53", "C").Resize(3, 120).Copy       'D&A
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("46", "AW").Resize(3, 120).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Becomes,

```
With Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports")
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("4", "AW").Resize(5, 120) = _
        .Cells("9", "C").Resize(5, 120).Value2         'Revenues
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("11", "AW").Resize(4, 120) = _
        .Cells("18", "C").Resize(4, 120).Value2        'Prod Costs
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("17", "AW").Resize(26, 120) = _
        .Cells("25", "C").Resize(26, 120).Value2       'Employee Related thru maintenance
    Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy).Cells("46", "AW") = _
        .Cells("53", "C").Resize(3, 120).Value2        'D&A
End With
```

As mentioned in comments, if the external files are at or over the 1Mb filesize area, save them as .XLSB (excel binary) to reduce load time.

Comment: Why you use "Value2", instead of "Value". Or that is just the way it is? And I would try to use XLSB after I change the code.

Comment: .Value2 is the raw underlying value without regional currency or date 'markers'. It is very slightly faster than .Value but you might change a date ,like 8/14/2017 into 42961 which you can format back into 8/14/2017.

Answer (score 1):

you can further clarify your code by defining worksheet object variables

this is same code section as @Jeeped posted

```
Dim wsTR As Worksheet
Dim wsTC As Worksheet

Set wsTR = Workbooks(NameFileOpen).Worksheets("Total_Reports")
Set wsTC = Workbooks(ModelFileName).Worksheets(TabCopy)


wsTC.Cells(4, "AW").Resize(5, 120) = wsTR.Cells(9, "C").Resize(5, 120).Value2       ' Revenues
wsTC.Cells(11, "AW").Resize(4, 120) = wsTR.Cells(18, "C").Resize(4, 120).Value2     ' Prod Costs
wsTC.Cells(17, "AW").Resize(26, 120) = wsTR.Cells(25, "C").Resize(26, 120).Value2   ' Employee Related thru maintenance
wsTC.Cells(46, "AW") = wsTR.Cells(53, "C").Resize(3, 120).Value2                    ' D&A
```

Comment: This one is very elegant! I will try it.